# 'TypeError("can't pickle generator objects"): Concurrent.future versus Asyncio

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I want to concurrently execute the same instance method from each object in a list in python.

I created a DataPipe class that downloads pages and stores the result in an array. Then when I'm done downloading the links of interest of a specific domain, I yield these pages and then yield from the pages the corresponding items.

The code works pretty much as expected and now, I want to download from mutliple domains at the same time.

```
class DownloadCommand(Command):

    def __init__(self, domain):
        self.domain = domain
        self.request_config = {'headers': self.domain.get_header(), 'proxy': self.domain.get_proxy()}
        self.data_pipe = DataPipe(command=self)

    def execute(self):
        # try:
        for brand, start_urls in self.domain.start_url.items():
            for start_url in start_urls:
                # yield from self.data_pipe.get_item_divs(brand, start_url)
                yield from self.data_pipe.get_item_divs(brand, start_url)`
```

Currently, I'm doing this sequentially.

```
def scrape(self):
   for domain in self.get_initial_domain_list():
        yield from self.fetch_from_dom(domain)

def fetch_from_dom(self, domain):
    self.set_current_domain(domain)
    for start_url_values, brand, start_url in domain.command.execute():
        for items in start_url_values:
            yield [self.get_item_value(item_div) for item_div in items]
```

I tried to multithread this application using `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` but it does not work for instance methods. Then when I used `pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool` it returned an error:

```
 multiprocess.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[<generator object fetch_from_dom at 0x7fa984814af0>]'. Reason: 'TypeError("can't pickle generator objects",)'
```

I want to switch to either `asyncio` or `concurrent.futures` but I'm not sure of which one would be better to do what I want that is if it's actually possible to do that in python(concurrently executing instance methods from objects in a list). Can anyone help?

Comment: I get that problem using Selenium and Multiprocessing, I solve it deleting/destroy the browser variable before run multiprocess and instance it inside each process.

Comment: Do you have an example of how you do that? @Wonka

Comment: Yes, just del variable_name. But using internal function to close opened browsers. Are you using Selenium?

Comment: Yes, I'm using selenuim though I'm pretty sure it's unrelated to the issue at hand.

Comment: Its related, cause multiprocess clone memory for each process, and system cant clone browser driver. I will post my clear function

Comment: Hey @TheEYL, did you resolve it??

Comment: No, what part of the code should I show you? I can't show the whole thing.  Should  I show you my DataPipe?

Answer (score 1):

Cant use selenium with python multiprocessing cause it clone memory. You can try to avoid more simple with threads. But this is my solution for multiprocessing

NOTE: self is my driver, cause I have custom class implemented over Selenium

```
#Exit function
def cleanup(self):
    print("++cleanup()++")
    try:
        try:
            self.close()
        except Exception as e:
            #print("except cleanup - 2 - self.close() -> %s" %e)
            pass

        try:
            self.quit()
        except Exception as e:
            #print("except cleanup - 3 - self.quit() -> %s" %e)
            pass


        try:
            self.dispose()
            #print("Fake disabled dispose()")
        except Exception as e:
            #print("except cleanup - 4 - self.dispose() -> %s" %e)
            pass


        try:
            self.service.process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
        except Exception as e:
            #print("except cleanup - 1 - self.service.process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM) -> %s" %e)
            pass

    except Exception as e:
        print("Except - CLEANUP -> %s" %e)
        #print(str(e))
        pass
```

In script code

```
#Before start threads
browser.cleanup()
del browser


#Now start multiprocessing and instance browser on each subprocess
```

Comment: and how would you do the multiprocessing?

Comment: Im using Pool (check ThreadPool if you want, its a "custom" class). Just iterate list of items, pool.map(your_function_work, (item, more_arguments...)) But you can do this part as you want

Comment: I removed all domains using selenium and kept only those using request to download the pages. I still have the same issue.

Comment: You have to destroy ALL selenium objects!! I supouse you main code get a list of URL's and then you want to scrape each on parallel. So start script, get list of urls, now KILL all seleniums (browser and del variable). Then run multiprocess and start Selenium on EACH subprocess. And do the same (kill browser, del variable_browser) at end of each subprocess (i missed that part). Good luck, I get stucked on that problem too much time ago and long days

Comment: oh I get it late, you means that now you are not using selenium just requests.... I should need to see full code to be more helpful